# Sort an array of floats. Result must be floats not list

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I would like to sort a very large array of floats. When I use sorted, the result is a list. However, I want a new array of floats.

Here is a short example:

```
    import numpy as np
    xmaxp = np.array([25.0, 5.0, 1.0],dtype=float)
    xmaxp_sorted = sorted(xmaxp)
```

Comment: `sorted` **always** returns a `list`, use the `numpy.ndarray` method `sort`, i.e. `xmaxp.sort()`

Comment: You can also use `np.sort(xmaxp)` if you don't want an inplace operation.

Answer (score 0):

as everybody else mentioned, use numpy sort method :

```
import numpy as np

xmaxp = np.array([25.0, 5.0, 1.0], dtype=float)
xmaxp_sorted = np.sort(xmaxp)
```

result :

```
[ 1.  5. 25.]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use np.array

```
np.array(xmaxp_sorted)
```